# Should my Node.js tests use HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, frameworks, httprequest

I have always thought in "Tests" as testing the role thing. I have seen that in many  (not to say all) cases, tests are performed just with logic, not considering the "role" thing. Small pieces of code being tested (unit tests).

In my mind, a test should check if the code is OK, and in order to do that, using a real "HTTP request" is the best way of achieving it (for a WebServer).

However, I have noticed that this practice is not well "recommended", I can't say why, but in most Frameworks that I have used, you couldn't test it with real requests, without hacking into something.

Is it something TERRIBLY BAD, or just "ok"? I mean, why mocking up something that can be tested for real...

I'm not sure this is covered by other questions, but if so, I couldn't find it.

Comment: What benefit does making an actual HTTP request have over passing a mocked HTTP request?

Comment: @Blender Mocking it doesn't consider for bad Routing problems, nor problem with response types, or even any header-related issue (caching, redirect..) (I'm not expert in this, but this is what I thought of)